# Install of qgis-mapserver fails in Centos7: missing dependencies

Tags: centos7, yum, qgis

Hello I'm trying to install qgis-mapserver on CentOS 7.3.

Here are the steps I followed:

- installed epel-release (v. 7.9) `yum install epel-release`
- added elgis 6: `sudo rpm -Uvh http://elgis.argeo.org/repos/6/elgis-release-6-6_0.noarch.rpm`
- made sure qgis-mapserver was available: `yum search qgis-mapserver` and it was (`qgis-mapserver.x86_64 : FCGI based OGC web map server`)
- tried to install: `yum install qgis-mapserver` and I get what seems to be a dependency issue

Here is the output:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.tobias-wollmann.com
 * epel: mirror.de.leaseweb.net
 * extras: mirror.crazynetwork.it
 * updates: centos.copahost.com
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package qgis-mapserver.x86_64 0:1.8.0-9_0.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: qgis(x86-64) = 1.8.0-9_0.el6 for package: qgis-mapserver-1.8.0-9_0.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libspatialindex.so.1()(64bit) for package: qgis-mapserver-1.8.0-9_0.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libqgis_core.so.1.8.0()(64bit) for package: qgis-mapserver-1.8.0-9_0.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libqgis_analysis.so.1.8.0()(64bit) for package: qgis-mapserver-1.8.0-9_0.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package qgis.x86_64 0:1.8.0-9_0.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libspatialite.so.2()(64bit) for package: qgis-1.8.0-9_0.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libspatialindex.so.1()(64bit) for package: qgis-1.8.0-9_0.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libqwtpolar.so.0()(64bit) for package: qgis-1.8.0-9_0.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libqwt.so.5()(64bit) for package: qgis-1.8.0-9_0.el6.x86_64
---> Package qgis-mapserver.x86_64 0:1.8.0-9_0.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libspatialindex.so.1()(64bit) for package: qgis-mapserver-1.8.0-9_0.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libspatialite.x86_64 0:2.4.0-0.6_0.RC4.el6 will be installed
---> Package qgis.x86_64 0:1.8.0-9_0.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libspatialindex.so.1()(64bit) for package: qgis-1.8.0-9_0.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libqwtpolar.so.0()(64bit) for package: qgis-1.8.0-9_0.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libqwt.so.5()(64bit) for package: qgis-1.8.0-9_0.el6.x86_64
---> Package qgis-mapserver.x86_64 0:1.8.0-9_0.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libspatialindex.so.1()(64bit) for package: qgis-mapserver-1.8.0-9_0.el6.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: qgis-1.8.0-9_0.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
           Requires: libqwtpolar.so.0()(64bit)
Error: Package: qgis-1.8.0-9_0.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
           Requires: libqwt.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: qgis-1.8.0-9_0.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
           Requires: libspatialindex.so.1()(64bit)
Error: Package: qgis-mapserver-1.8.0-9_0.el6.x86_64 (elgis)
           Requires: libspatialindex.so.1()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
** Found 3 pre-existing rpmdb problem(s), 'yum check' output follows:
ipa-client-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.6.x86_64 has installed conflicts freeipa-client: ipa-client-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.6.x86_64
ipa-client-common-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.6.noarch has installed conflicts freeipa-client-common: ipa-client-common-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.6.noarch
ipa-common-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.6.noarch has installed conflicts freeipa-common: ipa-common-4.4.0-14.el7.centos.6.noarch
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The ELGIS repository is not maintained any more, use EPEL starting with Centos 7.x

The package has been renamed (from **qgis-mapserver** to **qgis-server**) The EPEL Mapserver is now called
**qgis-server.x86_64** : FCGI-based OGC web map server

See also their mailing list. (http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/el/2017-April/thread.html)